# Form error produces program error instead of rendering rendering new view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a standard form object and one of the fields has a minimum length validation. However, when submitting the form with a string that is too short, I get a program error referring to `if @message.save!` in the controller method:

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in InvitationsController#create
Validation failed: Message is too short (minimum is 25 characters)`

So I get a program error instead of that it renders the new page again together with error message. What could be causing this behavior?

```
def create
  ... several variables get set first ...
  if @message.save!
    if !@hem.nil?
      MessageMailer.hem(@message).deliver_now
    elsif @hem.nil?
      MessageMailer.hem(@message).deliver_now
    end
    if logged_in_user?
      flash[:success] = "Yeah1"
    else
      flash[:success] = "Yeah2"
    end
    redirect_to messages_path
  else
    render 'new'  # also tried adding "and return"
  end
end
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for @message, url: messages_path do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  ...etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `save` rather than `save!` if you want the form rendered with errors.

The `save` method returns true if all validations succeed or false if any validations fail, whereas `save!` will actually throw a `RecordInvalid` exception that must be explicitly handled via `rescue`. Your use of `save!` is not actually returning a boolean value as you think it does.

Check the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) for additional details.